# Creating enum inside Model

Tags: swift, enums

I want to create an enum for order status like this

```
struct Order: Identifiable, Hashable {
var id: Int {
    return elementID
}
var elementID: Int
var orderNumber: String
enum Status: String {
    case complete = "Completed"
    case transit = "In Transit"
    case prepare = "Prepairing"
}
var date: String

func toString(forStatus status: Status) -> String {
    return status.rawValue
}
```

}

Then I want to create an order in the OrderList like this

```
struct OrderList {
static let listData: [Order] = [
    Order(elementID: 0, orderNumber: "123123123123", date: "15.08.2020", status: .transit)
]
```

}

Or like this

```
struct OrderList {
    static let listData: [Order] = [
        Order(elementID: 0, orderNumber: "123123123123", date: "15.08.2020").toString(forStatus: .complete))
    ]
}
```

But I can reach to status inside OrderList. How can I set a value in Order to Status?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you need to declare a `status` property in `Order`: `var status: Status`.

Comment: it looks like all you need is what @Sweeper suggested. Just declare a variable to hold the value of your order status. In your last example you're not initialising an Order you're creating an array of strings since your `toString(forStatus status: Status) -> String` function returns `String` not `Order`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add your status property to `Order`.

```swift
var status: Status
```

If you're going to nest `Status` (which you should!), then you should nest `List` as well.

```swift
extension Order {
  struct List {
    static let data = [
      Order(elementID: 0, orderNumber: "123123123123", date: "15.08.2020", status: .transit)
    ]
  }
}
```